# Ordering of filenames in linux - not purely lexicographical?

Tags: linux, sorting, ls

Given a few files in a directory `data` the following ls command provides a surprising result in the sense of how they are ordered:

```
for f in data/*; do echo $f;  done


data/CitiesBaselineCounts2015010520150112.49.csv
data/CitiesBaselineCounts2015010520150112.4.csv
data/CitiesBaselineCounts2015010520150112.50.csv
data/CitiesBaselineCounts2015010520150112.5.csv
data/CitiesBaselineCounts2015010520150112.6.csv
data/CitiesBaselineCounts2015010520150112.7.csv
data/CitiesBaselineCounts2015010520150112.8.csv
data/CitiesBaselineCounts2015010520150112.9.csv
data/CitiesBaselineCounts2015010520150112.csv
```

The `.` character is ascii 46- which precedes the codes for all of the digits (48 to 57).

So then the ordering is **not** lexicographical. What *are* the rules for the sorting used by the `ls` command?

Comment: [List files sorted numerically](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/33909)

Comment: @DavidPostill  Ok that's also helpful (and I will use it for this case) - but does not directly answer the lexicographical ordering.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you do `for f in data/*` the enumeration of filenames is being done by your shell not "ls". Normally, shells will sort lexicographically, (bash does) but they may use your LC_COLLATE locale collating sequence order. Perhaps your particular shell does not sort at all.

Directory entries are usually not sorted, but it depends on the underlying filesystem. Use `ls -f` to list a directory without sorting.

When you say `ls *`, first the shell expands * and may sort the result, then ls will sort the filenames again.

Comment: using bash here.

Comment: And what locale? Try  `export LC_COLLATE=C` in your script. Also, the filenames may not be ascii but in eg a utf8 encoding.

Comment: that export worked. wow that was non-intuitive. Any idea why would that not be the default behavior?

Comment: internationalisation is a big thing that non-programmers want to work exactly as they are used to in their paper dictionaries and so on. A lot of work has been done in linux to support this. However, it makes life difficult for many simple programming tasks, as you can see. I invariably set LANG=C (and LC_COLLATE=C and the all others) to avoid many such bizarre problems.

Answer (score 3):

ls, sort and your script all give the same ordering, which is lexicographic based on ASCII value of each position except that non-alphnumeric are ignored

> abc.
>   abc..
>   abc0
>   abc1
>   abc_1
>   abc.1
>   abc..1
>   abc.1.4
>   abc.1..4
>   abc.1.5
>   abc2
>   abc~2
>   abc_2
>   abc-2
>   abc.2
>   abc#2
>   abc%2
>   abc3
>   abc4
>   abc4.1
>   abc4.2
>   abc49
>   abc_9
>   abca
>   abcA
>   abcc

see the answer to question 631402 for more discussion including turning off locale which gives you lexicographic sorting by ASCII value including symbols